# How does mixing tracers and HP rounds affect burst-fire attacks?

Tags: combat, chronicles-of-darkness-1e, weapons

How does a character loading a FN90 with tracer bullets ×1, hollow point ×2, alternating, and then doing a short burst (3-round) or medium-long burst affect firing rules?

- Do they get the modifiers (bonuses and penalties) of both bullets, or does one supersede the other?
- How can the ST determine which bullets in a burst actually hit and which miss?

Comment: Aside from cheese / overcomplexification considerations, that's something people rarely do (intuitively made little sense to me, confirmed with a quick google search of "mixing ammo in magazine" ).

Comment: actually it states in the book Armory that most people load a tracer every 3-5 round: "Because of the excessive chemical residue tracers leave in a gun, most shooters load one tracer round for every three to five normal rounds. Some shooters also load the last few rounds in a magazine as tracers as a visual reminder to reload during the heat of battle, though this also tells the enemy that the subject is vulnerable."

Comment: Is your original question supposed to refer to tracker bullets or tracer bullets?

Comment: Oh Sorry its tracer, mistyped on the original question.

Comment: Armory is right and wrong. Tracers are generally loaded yes, every 3-5 rounds or so. They are loaded into support weapons--ie, machineguns, like the M240, PKMG, maybe SAW. Occasionally a squad commander will load them in their assault rifle as a way to very clearly indicate his desired target when directing fire, but this is not entirely standard. Note, for weapons with reliability issues, tracer/API rounds may greatly increase required maintenance to avoid jams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd give the penalties of all ammo in a burst. Since a burst gives you a slight bonus and hollow points give you a slight bonus (against unarmored targets), I'd apply a -1 to the roll to reflect the fact that one of the bullets you're firing isn't quite as good but gives the benefits of tracers.

Alternately, if you wanted a simpler and more powerful game, you could simply apply all the bonuses and all the penalties.

One GM I've played with for a long time has a good guideline that might apply here: if the players do it, the enemies can do it too. I'd give your players the heads-up that if they want to play an optimization game that you'll give them a commensurate challenge when it comes to optimizing the NPCs.

Comment: You are wrong about impracticality of mixed ammo. at least Armory contradicts that. 
I'm also thinking something along the line of roll to see which ammo took effect.

Comment: If Armory contradicts this, does it have suggested rules?

Comment: Unfortunately No, that's why I'm asking here. according to armory, tracer rounds are usually loaded between other types of ammo, to increase visibility on bursts and also to warn the user about the low ammo situation.

Comment: Your tracer/API round will indeed have different ballistics from your ball or HP round. At the reasonable ranges for the little, fast, 5.7mm round though, it won't make a difference.

Comment: Knowing that you're talking about tracers changes my answer somewhat; I've edited.